# How to determine if tkinter Toplevel widget exists.?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a need to destroy a `Toplevel` widget if it already exists before creating it.  I've researched this and every response I can find here and elsewhere suggest using `winfo_exists`; however, the following code demonstrates that doesn't work.  It fails with the error: object has no attribute 'toplevel'

I can use a brute force try:/except: to destroy the widget, but surely there's a better way.

BTW: I am on Windows 10 running Python 3.11.1

```
# does_widger_exists.py

import tkinter as tk


class TL_GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('300x100')
        self.root.title('Tkinter Test')
        button0 = tk.Button(self.root,text='Create Toplevel',command=self.makeToplevel).pack(pady=20)
        self.root.mainloop()
 
    def makeToplevel(self):
        if tk.Toplevel.winfo_exists(self.toplevel):
            self.toplevel.destroy()
        self.toplevel = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.toplevel.geometry('500x100')
        self.toplevel.title('I am a TopLevel')
        text0 = tk.Label(self.toplevel,text='Hello World',height=1,width=25,borderwidth=5).pack()
 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TL_GUI()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to initialize `self.toplevel` to some value in your `__init__` method so the first call to `makeToplevel` doesn't fail when it gets to the conditional; as written, `self.toplevel` doesn't exist when the check is first run. With this fix, subsequent calls to `makeToplevel` will work as expected

```
def __init__(self):
    self.root = tk.Tk()
    self.root.geometry('300x100')
    self.root.title('Tkinter Test')

    self.toplevel = None  # initialize this instance variable

    button0 = tk.Button(
        self.root,
        text='Create Toplevel',
        command=self.makeToplevel
    ).pack(pady=20)
    self.root.mainloop()
```

You should also update the condition checked by the `if` statement as follows:

```
def makeToplevel(self):
    if self.toplevel and self.toplevel.winfo_exists():  # make this change
        self.toplevel.destroy()
    self.toplevel = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
    self.toplevel.geometry('500x100')
    self.toplevel.title('I am a TopLevel')
    text0 = tk.Label(
        self.toplevel,
        text='Hello World',
        height=1,
        width=25,
        borderwidth=5
    ).pack()
```

Oh, and one final note: using `pack()` like you are on `button0` and `text0` can cause trouble if you're not careful! As written, `button0` and `text0` will both always evaluate to `None` since that's the value returned by `pack()`. If you want to refer to these widgets anywhere else, you should `pack()` them on a separate line, e.g.:

```
button0 = tk.Button(...)  # now 'button0' is equal to the Button object, not None
button0.pack(...)

text0 = tk.Label(...)  # now 'text0' is equal to the Label object, not None
text0.pack(...)
```

Comment: Exception raised on `self.toplevel.winfo_exists()` because `self.toplevel` is `None`.

Comment: Thanks, but now I get this error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'winfo_exists'

Comment: @JRiggles Thanks for the fix - it works now.  BTW: I put the pack() on the same line in this demo code, but normally I put pack, grid, place on a separate line. Thanks again.

Comment: @Pragmatic_Lee Glad I could help! And it's always nice to hear people are adhering to best practices ;) If this answer worked for you, please mark it as "accepted" so other folks know this question has been answered.